# C# Enabling Edit and Continue for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can we use **Edit and Continue** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx) for a **Windows Phone** project?

I've tried changing the Debugging options and trying different things but keep having a popup that says: "Source code changes are not allowed while debugging the current project type"

The code is in Break mode.
I'm using **Visual Studio 2015 Preview** and the project type is **Windows Phone Silverlight (8.1)** (C#)

Has anyone had success editing code in break mode (with this or other project type/visual studio version)?

Comment: I would be really surprised if Edit-and-Continue would work for Windows Phone. It's only with VS2013 that we even could do that for x64 projects. The feature requires being able to update the executable in-memory, which is a non-trivial operation. I doubt it's supported on Windows Phone (emulated or remote debugging).

Comment: The point is not to be able to "continue", but to "edit" - eg having the simulator run, and changing some code while looking at the running app (eg for guessing at necessary changes for positioning elements). It's really annoying not to be able to do that, and for me it did work until a few days ago, and now it doesn't anymore - and I have no clue why it stopped working.

Comment: Silly me - found it, just disabling "Edit and Continue" makes it possible to just "Edit" while running ... doh! ...